# How might you make a Rails test fixture persistent between tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, persistence, fixtures, testing

I have a good half-dozen fixtures in my Rails test suite - some quite large - that represent static look-up tables in the database.  Since their values theoretically don't change, I'd like to save the time of wiping and reloading the tables between each test.  Is there a trick/plug-in/gem/hack to demarcate these fixtures as only needing to be loaded once before all the tests run and not wiped between each?

Answer (score 0):

You can desactivate rollback transaction in all your test.

Or you can add this fixtures before all of your test. Before the begin of transaction.